# Grabbing text from a cell to use in a sentence in another cell - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

On Google Sheets, I'm trying to use the text in one cell (say B4 contains: "Janet") and reference it in a sentence in another cell (say G4 is: "Hi {Enter B4 here}, I'm reaching out to you today...")

A little background: I have about 130 columns of data that contain websites, first name, email, and vendor type that I hope to reference in an out reach email that I just copy down across a series of columns.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this with a formula and copy down:

```
 ="Hi "& B4 &", I'm reaching out to you today..."
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you

Comment: If this works for you, please approve the answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Вячеслав Гордиевский  It works fine with United States Locale. Your locale might be causing your problem. I don't know your locale setting, but you might try single quotes around & B4&.

Comment: Might want to make the spaces around the ampersands consistent to make it easier to understand

Comment: Fabien Warniez Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is entirely what you want but this will do a replacement.  It looks for a structure like this {{A2}} with a cell in A1Notation in the center.  You must selected the cell with the text that you want to perform the replacement in.

```
function mergeReplace() 
{
  var re=/\{\{[A-Z]{1,2}\d{1,3}\}\}/g;  
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('Matches');
  var rng=sht.getActiveRange();
  var a1=rng.getA1Notation();
  var s=rng.getValue();
  var matches=s.match(re);
  for(var i=0;i<matches.length;i++)
  {
    var r=matches[i].slice(2,-2);
    s=s.replace(matches[i],sht.getRange(r).getValue());
  }
  rng.setValue(s);
}
```

Here's what my data looked like:

Before Replacement:

[image]

After Replacement:

[image]

Comment: This is actually very helpful. Thanks so much!